# Check which application is toggling the proxy switches on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, proxy

On my `Windows 10` machine, the "Use Setup Script" switch in `Network and Internet` settings keeps getting toggled on with a script address. This is a private laptop, but with some workplace applications installed. The problem is that this proxy switch interferes with both regular browsing as well as automated tasks, and it is irritating to keep turning it off.

I have checked `gpedit.msc` to check if something is setting a policy there, checked `scheduled tasks` to see if there is something which would periodically write to this switch field and turn it on, but did not find anything interesting. Nothing crops up when I specifically search for that proxy script address in my system files either.

I tried disabling the switch from `gpedit.msc`, but it still gets turned on with the text filed filled in with the proxy address, and greyed out for me, since I disabled access, so whatever is writing to it, has some permissions.

Is there a way to find out exactly which application is turning on this proxy, or is there a way to disable this field completely so it cannot be written / overwritten by any other application / process?

Comment: I assume the value shown is also here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\ManualProxies`  Could you setup Process Monitor with a filter for that key to see which process is writing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "with bot regular browsing"?

Comment: @Ramhound Ah I meant "botH", typing eror. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @HelpingHand It was actually this registry entry - `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL` whiich is being written to again, and value set to the proxy address. The application doing it is `svchost.exe`, with the command line parameters as `svchost.exe -k netsvcs -p -s gpsvc`. Is that a group policy enforcer? Any way to narrow it down?

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\gpsvc\Parameters`  %SystemRoot%\System32\gpsvc.dll - Group Policy Client.  I would run: `gpresult /Z > gpz.txt` and/or rsop.msc.

Comment: @HelpingHand I tried it out, got some results. Indeed being set by a group policy. I'll investigate further on how to get this pesky thing turned off.